# How to know the total occurrences of a word in a string and retrieve data from it in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like this

```
$myString = "Itwas%AC%4D%AC%4A%5BL3%BF5,T3,S13%4A%5Bbound over%AC%4A%5BC6%4A%5B%5D%AC%4A%5BL7%BF11%4A%5Ball good people to come"
```

My requirement is to count the no of occurrences of %4A%5B and get the data in between two %4A%5B and store in an array.

Example:

```
1)L3%BF5,T3,S13
2)C6
3)L7%BF11
```

In the above string there are 6 occurrences of it. So I want to know that in run time and fetch the data in between %4A%5B and store in an array.

Comment: `perldoc -f split` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965202/how-to-know-the-total-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-and-retrieve-data-from-i#comment22754649_15965202)  with `%4A%5B` as split pattern, then count the number of elements in the resulting array:

```
$myString = "Itwas%AC%4D%AC%4A%5BL3%BF5,T3,S13%4A%5Bbound over%AC%4A%5BC6%4A%5B%5D%AC%4A%5BL7%BF11%4A%5Ball good people to come";
@array = split /%4A%5B/, $myString;
$num = @array - 1;

use Data::Dumper;
print "Occurrences: $num\n";
print Dumper(@array);
```

Output:

```
Occurrences: 6
$VAR1 = 'Itwas%AC%4D%AC';
$VAR2 = 'L3%BF5,T3,S13';
$VAR3 = 'bound over%AC';
$VAR4 = 'C6';
$VAR5 = '%5D%AC';
$VAR6 = 'L7%BF11';
$VAR7 = 'all good people to come';
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can't the variables var1,var3, var5, var7 be ignored while splitting? I just want the data which is in between two %4A%5B.

Comment: @RaviKumar The variables are just used by `Data::Dumper` to print the array content - you can just omit this. The data you want is in `@array`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also count regex matches like so:

```
my @matches = $myString =~ /%4A%5B/g;
print scalar(@matches)
```